# Как правильно доставлять данные по сети

Tags: c, tcp

Допустим я три раза на сервере выполняю вызов `send`

```
send(sock,"I",sizeof("I"),0);
send(sock,"Y",sizeof("Y"),0);
send(sock,"X",sizeof("X"),0);
```

На стороне клиента же три раза выполняю вызов `recv`

```
recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
```

Иногда происходит так, что три вызова send выполняются быстрее , чем данные приходят к клиенту, таким образом первый вызов recv считывает все отправленные тремя вызовами send данные, а второй recv замирает в ожидании, приходится делать "подстраховки":

Клиент принимает данные первого вызова send, после чего отправляет положительный ответ серверу, и следующий вызов send на сервере выполняется только после принятия положительного ответа от клиента, это крайне колхозно, поэтому если вы знаете нормальный способ - напишите ответ

Comment: я думаю проще взять https://github.com/zeromq

Answer (score 14, accepted):

С *программной* точки зрения TCP представляет двухсторонний поток данных, и эти данные могут доставляться произвольными кусками за раз, как меньшими так и большими. Делить этот поток на сообщения нужно средствами своего протокола, который работает поверх TCP.

Есть несколько основных способов:

1. Отправлять и читать сообщения фиксированной длины.

   ```
   #define MSG_SZ 64
   // ...
   char buf[MSG_SZ];
   strncpy("X", buf, MSG_SZ-1); buf[MSG_SZ-1]=0; send(sock, buf, MSG_SZ, 0);
   strncpy("Y", buf, MSG_SZ-1); buf[MSG_SZ-1]=0; send(sock, buf, MSG_SZ, 0);
   ```

   Приём:

   ```
   char buf[MSG_SZ];
   recv(sock, buf, MSG_SZ, MSG_WAITALL);
   recv(sock, buf, MSG_SZ, MSG_WAITALL);
   ```
2. Использовать разделяющий символ/строку.

   ```
   #define MSG_SEP "\n<NEXT>\n"
   #define MSG_SEP_LEN (sizeof(MSG_SEP) - 1)
   // ...
   send(sock, "X", sizeof("X")-1, 0); send(sock, MSG_SEP, MSG_SEP_LEN, 0);
   send(sock, "Y", sizeof("Y")-1, 0); send(sock, MSG_SEP, MSG_SEP_LEN, 0);
   ```

   Приём:

   ```
   char *recvMsg(int sock) {
     static char buf[BUF_SZ]; // буфер статический, так что будет сохраняться между вызовами
     static size_t recv_n = 0; //< колличество данных в буфере
     char *sep_pos;    //< позиция разделителя

     while(1) {
       ssize_t recv_rv = 0; 
       sep_pos = memmem(buf, recv_n, MSG_SEP, MSG_SEP_LEN) // сначала ищем разделитель т.к. предыдущий вызов мог прочитать несколько сообщений. 
       // memmem — нестандартная функция для поиска подстроки в памяти аналогичная strstr
       if (sep_pos) {
         break;
       }

       // Получение дополнительных данных
       ssize_t recv_rv = recv(sock, buf + recv_n, BUF_SZ - recv_n, 0);

       if (recv_rv<0) {
         if (errno == EINTR) {
           continue; // Системный вызов был прерван сигналом.
                     // Эту ситуацию желательно обрабатывать на unix-подобных ОС
         } else {
           error_or_die(); // обработка других ошибок, например разрыва соединения
           return 0;
         }
       } else if (recv_rv == 0) {
         // соединение закрыто и данных в сокете больше нет, но стоп-строка не найдена.
         error_or_die();
         return 0;
       } else { // прочитано несколько символов. Добавим их длину.
         recv_n+=recv_rv;
         if (recv_n==BUF_SZ) { // Буфер переполнен.
           error_or_die();
           return 0;
         }
       }
     }

     assert (sep_pos);

     // Обрезка одного сообщения
     size_t rv_len = sep_pos-buf;
     char *rv = malloc(rv_len+1);
     assert(rv);
     memncpy(buf, rv, rv_len);
     rv[rv_len] = 0;

     // Сдвиг оставшихся в буфере данных в начало
     recv_n -=( rv_len + MSG_SEP_LEN);
     memncpy(sep_pos + MSG_SEP_LEN, buf, recv_n);

     return rv;
   }

   // ...

   char *buf1 = recvMsg(sock); /* ... */  free (buf1);
   char *buf2 = recvMsg(sock); /* ... */  free (buf2);
   ```
3. Отправлять размер сообщения перед ним/в его заголовке.

   ```
   const char *msg="X";
   uint32_t sz = strlen(msg);
   uint32_t nsz = htonl(nsz); // перевод размера сообщения в сетевой порядок байт.
   // Вообще говоря, это не обязательно, но необходимо удостоверится, 
   // что обе машины ожидают данные с одинаковым порядком байт совпадает.
   send(sock, &nsz, 4, 0); send(sock, msg, sz, 0);
   msg="Y"; sz = strlen(msg);
   nsz = htonl(nsz)
   send(sock, &nsz, 4, 0); send(sock, msg, sz, 0);
   ```

   Приём:

   ```
   uint32_t sz;

   recv(sock, &sz, 4, MSG_WAITALL);
   sz = ntohl(sz);
   recv(sock, buf, sz, MSG_WAITALL);

   recv(sock, &sz, 4, MSG_WAITALL);
   sz = ntohl(sz);
   recv(sock, buf, sz, MSG_WAITALL);
   ```
4. Отправлять в одном соединении только одно сообщение.

   ```
   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
   connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr);
   send(sock, "X", sizeof("X"), 0);
   shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
   /* получение ответа */
   close(sock)

   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr);
   send(sock, "Y", sizeof("Y"), 0);
   shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
   /* получение ответа */
   close(sock);
   ```

   Приём:

   ```
   sock = accept(srv_sock, 0, 0);
   size_t recv_n = 0;
   ssize_t recv_rv;

   while (1) {
     recv_rv = recv (sock, buf+recv_n, BUF_SZ - recv_n, 0);
     if (recv_rv<0) {
       error_or_die(); /* обработка ошибок */
     } else if (recv_rv == 0) {
       break;
     } else { // recv_rv > 0
       recv_n += recv_rv
     }
   }

   /* формирование ответа */

   close(sock);

   /* приём следующего соединения аналогичен */
   ```

Все подходы могут использоваться в различных комбинациях и у каждого подхода есть плюсы и минусы. Например, (1) подходит только для очень простых протоколов, то по факту он же используется в примере (3) для «заголовка»; В HTTP для заголовка используется способ (2), а для содержимого (3) или, в старых версиях, (4).

Также следует помнить о том, что за один раз может придти не только больше, но и меньше данных, поэтому в примерах выше используется MSG_WAITALL или полноценный цикл чтения с буферизацией, как в (2) и (4). С точки зрения накладных расходов на локальную систему обычно аналогичный цикл чтения в пользовательском пространстве предпочтителен и для остальных вариантов. А для случае сервера, обслуживающего множество клиентов он будет зачастую обязателен.

---

<sup>**Дисклеймер:** Весь код написан умозрительно для иллюстрации принципов, не отлажет и может содержать ошибки.</sup>

Comment: Отличный ответ!