# Winsock: функция recv - получение данных

Tags: c++, c, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите пожалуйста, в функции recv непонятен один момент:

> Возвращаемое значение Если ошибок не происходит, recv возвращает
> количество полученных байтов, и буфер, на который указывает параметр
> buf, будет содержать эти полученные данные. Если соединение было
> корректно закрыто, возвращаемое значение равно нулю.

Вроде все понятно, но:

```
std::string my_string_buff;
my_string_buff.resize(100);

int my_recv = recv(my_socket, &my_string_buff[0], my_string_buff.size(), 0);
```

Предположим я выделил буфер для приема из 100 байт и предположим сервер мне выслал сообщение равное именно 100 байтам, то есть я получил полностью все данные от сервера, НО так как я заранее размер получаемых данных не знаю, мне нужно вызвать recv еще раз и так как данные от севера уже получены, то второй вызов вернет 0, и по описанию - это будет означать, что сервер закрыл сокет, но это же не обязательно так!
Если я общаюсь по http и попросил keep-alive, то сокет будет открыт, но функция recv все равно вернет 0, так как данных на данный момент нет.

И вот непонятно, как обрабатывать этот момент.

Comment: Надо либо сначала получить от сервера размер данных, либо использовать маркер окончания передачи. То бишь всегда узнавать об окончании передачи из прикладного протокола, а не из сокетов.

Comment: @user7860670, вы имеете ввиду внутри самых получаем кусков http сообщений, не дожидаясь итогового результата от recv ?

Comment: Если используется протокол http, то размер передаваемых данных и признак их окончания задается протоколом.

Comment: @user7860670 не всегда в HTTP есть заголовок Content-Length (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2 ) .  Если заголовка нет, данные надо принимать до тех пор, пока сервер их шлет.

Comment: @gbg Если в HTTP нету Content-Length, то надо читать пока не встетится особый признак конца данных, а не пока шлёт. Пока шлёт - это ненадёжный вариант. Для chunked - это чанк с нулём + возврат каретки. HTTP протокол чётко детерминирует конец посылки.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо за уточнение

Comment: nick_n_a, а как выгадает этот признак конца данных? EOF ? В RFC7230 - не нашел такого просто.

Comment: @Optimus1 Пункт 4.1 описывает. `chunked-body   = *chunk   last-chunk trailer-part CRLF`  *The chunked transfer coding is complete
   when a chunk with a chunk-size of zero is received, possibly followed
   by a trailer, and finally terminated by an empty line.* что приблизительно переводится... завершение, когда встерился чанк с размером ноль, и вконце завершающая пустая строка.

Comment: EOF для сокета не всегда уместен. KeepAlive сокет не будет иметь EOF, потому что сокет не закрыт. Поэтому признак конца определяется либо `Content-Length` либо определёной комбинацией байт, заканчивающейся для HTTP как правило CRLF.

Comment: @nick_n_a, как правило. Но я так не смог понять из RFC7230 - где бы четко было написано, что конец данных - это символ или комбинация символов такая. Насчет chank`ов есть в Пункт 4.1, который вы указали и CRLF в пункте   A.2. Изменения по сравнению с RFC 2616 - но там тоже, как то все запутано, ну по крайней мере для меня.

Comment: О, есть пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/5674955/5727271  Двойной LFCR признак конца (т.е. пустая строка между двумя LFCR) для chunked (только  LFCR проверяются снаружи обвёртки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> то второй вызов вернет 0, и по описанию - это будет означать, что сервер закрыл сокет, но это же не обязательно так!

Это не так. По умолчанию `recv()` будет ждать пока данные не появятся. Также он может вернуть `-1`, если сокет находится в неблокирующем режиме и данные ещё не пришли или вызов будет прерван сигналом с установкой соответствующий ошибки `EAGAIN` или `EINTR`.

Возврат нуля для tcp-сокета в невырожденной ситуации — это надёжный признак закрытия соединения второй стороной.

ЗЫ: Также стоит помнить, что с прикладной точки зрения TCP представляет из себя поток байт. Разделение его на сообщения следует делать по средствам протоколов более высоких уровней. Как именно — уже писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158547/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8/1158644#1158644).

Answer (score 1):

Неа, вы поняли неправильно. Если вы считали сто байт, а потом попытаетесь читать еще раз, вы получите не ноль - просто ваша программа заблокируется на функции `recv`, и будет стоять до тех пор, пока не получит хотя бы байт, или сервер со своей стороны не закроет соединение.

У вас есть два-с половиной варианта управлять этой ситуацией - сделать сокет асинхронным, и тогда вы получите отрицательное значение, а в `errono` будет что-то типа `EAGAIN` (`EWOULDBLOCK`) - так система вам намекнет, что данных для вас у нее нет.

Половина варианта, доступная на линуксе - сделать не весь сокет неблокирующим, а только данную операцию, подставив флаг `MSG_NONBLOCK`

И еще вариант - перед чтением проверять, что в сокет что-то пришло. Это всякие `poll`, `select` и их вариации.

Comment: "система вам намекнет, что данных для вас у нее нет." - а как система может понять, что данных у нее для меня уже нет ? Если Соединение TCP остается открытым ?

Comment: Так если байты не пришли - значит их нет.

Comment: так они могут прийти через минуту или час. TCP - это же по сути кран, с которого может капать раз в час, а может литься постоянно.

Comment: Другая сторона соединения может со своей стороны закрыть сокет, и тогда вы получите ноль.

Comment: ключевой момент - "Если Соединение TCP остается открытым"

Comment: Система вам сообщает, что в данный момент новые данные от другой стороны не поступили (если сокет неблокирующий), или останавливает поток до тех пор, пока данные не поступят.